# Windows 8 Store - Debug App Downloaded from store

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to debug a Windows Store app downloaded from the store? I have the source code from the build I uploaded, but no breakpoints are working.

The reason I ask is that in-app purchases aren't working in the live store, but they work fine in test mode. I need to see the exception being thrown--which is caught by the app and printed to `Debug.WriteLine`, but I don't see it in the console either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it works if you follow these steps:

```
Debug->Debug Installed App Package
```

Make sure that "Debug this code type:" says "Mixed (Managed and Native)"

Once I checked that box, it worked fine, but of course debugging was pretty slow.

PS - You also have to include the symbol files in the original build uploaded to the store. This is a good reason to always do this.